# dask workers freeze on file writing

Tags: dask, distributed

I am in a situation where I need to write a large dataset on disk and have issues avoiding workers to "freeze": the memory keeps increasing up until it reaches the pause fraction (0.5) and then nothing goes on anymore (according to the dashboard).
I tried to work on a minimal example but cannot reproduce such behavior as I am reading a large dataset.

How could I proceed with debugging in such a situation?

Platform is HPC.

distributed is configured according to:

```
    memory:
      target: false  # target fraction to stay below
      spill: false  # fraction at which we spill to disk
      pause: 0.50  # fraction at which we pause worker threads
      terminate: 0.95  # fraction at which we terminate the worker
```

Here an overview of the graph for the writing of a subset of 2 files:

[dask graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tizUf.png)

Comment: I have also met this problem. Do you figure it out? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your workers are running out of memory.  Unfortunately I don't know why without knowing a lot more about your program.  Some common solutions to this:

1. Use smaller chunks
2. Use Dask workers with more memory
3. Turn off the memory pause feature, and hope that your computation can finish in the provided space
4. Add more Dask workers
5. Restructure your computation differently so that Dask can clear out data as it creates it
6. ...

There are many things that could be going on here.  Unfortunately it is difficult to tell without knowing much more about what you are trying to do (which is of course hard to do and respect everyone's time).